# Localize LaunchImage

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I'm unable to find the localization property of launch images. Has this been removed from Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think localization of LaunchImage is possible. You can look at using Launch Storyboard though and get full flexibility.